# Hibernate EntityManager + Query Cache - "join fetch" not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, join, fetch, query-cache

I am trying to cache a query like this:

```
TypedQuery<Foo> q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT foo FROM Foo foo " +
    "INNER JOIN FETCH Foo.bar "
);
q.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
```

The problem is that the `FETCH` doesn't seem to have any effect when the cache is hit, i.e. the collection Foo.bar doesn't get initialized. I could iterate over the the result list and initialize all instances of the collection by hand, but that would make the whole thing even slower than without using the query cache in the first place.

I use JBoss AS 6.0 / Hibernate 3.6 with Infinispan as cache engine.

Curiously, according to the cache statistics I get through the JMX console, objects in Foo.bar seem to get cached, but the cache for those objects doesn't get any hits.

Answer (score 2):

It can be fixed by applying `@Cache` to the collection property (of course, target entity should be cacheable too), see [21.2.1. Cache mappings](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-cache-mapping).

Comment: Thanks, it seems that I still have to iterate over result list and initialize the collections, although they are now loaded from the cache instead of the database. Doesn't really solve my problem, because in my real world application I have a relatively complex object graph which I have to partially fetch, and iterating over all the collections, some of which have dependencies themselves which I need to fetch as well, eats away any performance benefits I might gain from caching.

Comment: @chris : maybe you should try to see if an EntityGraph could match your needs.